# Power Point: How to transform singular layouts into slide masters?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Newbie question here,

I downloaded a Power Point template and started to happily edit it, only to find out that I wasn't editing the Slide Masters but singular slides. When I went to "add a new slide" I found out my Slide Masters to be empty.

Is there a way for me to "migrate" my work on singular slides to Master Slides?

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: You mention both "singular layouts" and "singular slides".  Layouts are part of the slide master, slides are not. Which do you actually mean?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to singular slides! That's what I was editing, and I'd like to make them Master Slides or Singular Layouts, whatever it makes more sense so I can use them later on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note what layout your slide is based on; with the slide in the main window, click the triangle next to "Layout" on the Home tab. The current layout will be highlighted.

The do View | Slide Master and choose to COPY the layout the slide's based on. That'll give you a new layout to modify but it'll have all the same placeholders as the original. You don't want to delete these.

But you DO want to delete all the non-placeholder stuff from the new layout, then copy/paste all the non-placeholder stuff from your slide TO the new layout. You may need to adjust the layering with Send To Front/Back, but that should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thanks! Going slider by slider, and changing View Modes to see the correspondent layout, and Copy/pasting contents across did the trick. Thank you!